# Intensity of light wave penetrating soft tissue

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, scattering, absorption

I'm studying for a medical physics exam and I'm struggling with the following question:

> Calculate the fraction of energy which penetrates to a depth of 3cm in soft tissue for a beam of light at a wavelength of 1030nm

I'm also given the following data:

> absorption coefficient 0.5 cm^(-1)
>
> scattering coefficient 50 cm^(-1)
>
> anisotropy factor g = 0.95

And I know that the correct answer is 0.00012, but I have absolutely no idea how to reach this result.

I attempted using the Beer-Lambert law with the absorption and scattering coefficients, but with the absorption it gave 0.22 and with the scattering it gave 7.18x10^(-66), which are clearly both way off. (I didn't expect this to give the right result, because I realise I should be using the anisotropy factor somehow, but I can't find ANYTHING about how to use it in this context anywhere).

Any pointers?

Comment: Well, I played around with the numbers, and I can't get 0.00012 out of it with those numbers.  It's also been a while since I thought about radiation penetration distance calculations.  Is there any more information in the problem?  Are you sure you have the numbers and units right?  Sorry, and good luck!

Comment: @Brionius Nope, that's all the information (it's a multi part question with a few other beams, and all other information is about the other beams, which I've been able to get the right answer for). Yeah, numbers and units are definitely right (copy and pasted from the past exam paper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty straight forward:

$\mu = \alpha_a + \alpha_s (1-g)$

where $\mu$ is the overall attenuation coefficient, $\alpha_a$ is the absorption coefficient, $\alpha_s$ is the scattering coefficient and $g$ is the anisotropy factor.

So $\mu = 0.5 + 50(1-0.95) = 3$

Putting that into the Beer-Lambert equation, with $x = 3cm$ gives:

$I/I_0 = \exp(-\mu x) = \exp(-3*3) = 0.00012$

which is the correct solution.